# Quadrature encoder (unknown) pinout

Tags: encoder, pinout, phototransistor, quadrature

I have a quadrature photoresistor from a printer.

I want to determine the pinout. I can't find a datasheet for it. The case only shows "80058 - 96315" and I don't know the pinout.

The two phototransistors should have common GND and VCC, and separate channels.

Which pin is which?

I think B is GND and D is VCC, so A and C should be the two channels for the quadrature, however I'm not sure about it.

I switched my multimeter to "diode test mode" and got these readings:

[image: Multimeter Test]

This is the photoresistor:

[image: Photoresistor]

I need some help to label each pin.

I found this old post that has the same PCB as i have https://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/avago-optical-encoder-pinoutdatasheet/ but nothing...

And this but nothing again https://reprap.org/wiki/Optical_encoders_01

The encoder is an Avago 96315 but there is no information nor datasheets about this item...

Comment: What makes you think this is a quadrature phototransistor? Why do you call it a photoresistor in your post? By "continuity mode" do you mean "diode test mode"? Click the [edit]  link ...

Comment: This would be easier with a multimeter which has "diode-check" mode.  The forward voltage of some diodes can be greater than 1.0v also.

Comment: "continuity mode" do you mean "diode test mode"?  ---> Yes, sorry, mistranslation. It is diode mode. And I'm prety sure that it is a quadrature photoresistor, I did not take a photo from the other side, but the shape is the same that commons quadrature encoder like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v1Ra.jpg. So it has 2 phototransistors inside both with common VCC and GND and separate base...